# Why did O'Brien leave Downton Abbey?

Tags: downton-abbey

What was the reason for O'Brien to leave the series *Downton Abbey* with no explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was explained in the show. She decided to become lady's maid of [Susan MacClare](http://downtonabbey.wikia.com/wiki/Susan_MacClare).

It was in the [first episode of the fourth season](http://downtonabbey.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_4.0) (I don't remember if it was shown or only mentioned).

From [her page](http://downtonabbey.wikia.com/wiki/Sarah_O%27Brien) on Downton Abbey Wiki:

> In February 1922, she sneaked away in the night to travel to India to
>   be a lady's maid to Susan MacClare, Marchioness of Flintshire.

Later we find out that she made a career in India:

> According to Mrs Hughes, by 1924, Miss O'Brien had been employed by
>   the new Governor's wife in India.

Comment: it was rather abrupt though